# Painted over refrigerator water shut off valve

Tags: refrigerator, valve, paint-removal

A while back I hired a contractor to paint my home and the idiot spray painted over the refrigerator water valve. The refrigerator I had then wasn’t connected to the water line because I never used the ice maker. We are getting a new refrigerator delivered tomorrow and I’m worried this might be an issue when installing the water line. How do I remove the paint around it? Will a paint stripper from Home Depot work? Please help I really need that fridge installed tomorrow. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the valve turn/work?  Paint should not bother it too much.

Comment: Post a photo, please.

Comment: Yes, use paint striper, or face problems with seal.

Comment: Acrilic paint dissolved by toluene, lacquer thinner has it. But it has strong odour. Acetone works too, but it may destroy some plastic components of faucet.

Comment: Are the threads (if any) painted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.